# Ubuntu Core as Hyper-V virtual machine image

Tags: ubuntu, virtual-machine, images, hyper-v, iot

As Ubuntu Core can be installed on an Intel® NUC, is there any possbility to make it run as Hyper-V virtual machine to play around with it?

Comment: This is rather a windows question than a Unix & Linux question, as Hyper-V is Windows software.

Comment: at "Ask Ubuntu" I was told to place the question here. At the end, the question is, can Ubuntu Core install/run in a Virtual Machine be it VMware,VirtualBox or Hyper-V running on Linux or Windows host.   
   In the next step, you can deal with the flavor of each combination

Comment: Well did you try it?

Comment: not yet, as the install isn't that straight forward. So I'm wondering if there is anyone who has already gone through this challange.

Answer (score 0):

I have successfully installed it in Hyper-V.

I followed [Install Ubuntu Core on the Intel® NUC | Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/download/intel-nuc) whereby I used a virtual disk do get `dawson-uc18-m7-20190122-10.img.xz`into the VM. 
I created a virtual disk as described in [How to Attach and Copy files from a VHD in Windows 10](https://www.groovypost.com/howto/attach-copy-files-vhd-windows-10/) 
mounted it in Win 10, copied the downloaded files, set it offline to include it in the VM as described on [How to Access Local and USB Hard Drives In Your Hyper-V Virtual Machine](https://www.howtogeek.com/223193/how-to-access-local-and-usb-hard-drives-in-your-hyper-v-virtual-machine/).
Afterwards, I started the VM, went online and browsed to the tutorial to copy the commands, run the commands and done.

There are only two things:

- do a hard restart, restarting via the live-image won't work
- the username for ssh is given in your user account, it is not your email.